# Exporting Postgres Rows as a JSON File

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I need to generate a JSON file for a dataTables section on my web site. The format of the JSON should look like this:

```
{
        "data": [
                [
                        "Tiger Nixon",
                        "System Architect",
                        "Edinburgh",
                        "5421",
                        "2011/04/25",
                        "$320,800",
                ],
                [
                        "Garrett Winters",
                        "Accountant",
                        "Tokyo",
                        "8422",
                        "2011/07/25",
                        "$170,750"
                ],
        ]
}
```

This format looks like an array of arrays listed on the [JSON Creation Functions (Table 9-42.)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) -- array_to_json.

However, my data is not stored as arrays in my database.  It's typical row data.

But when I try to export to JSON using "row_to_json" -- the format is way off from what I need.  [See this SQLfiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9b641/1)

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the best approach to make the JSON export look more like the format pasted above.

Should I be reformatting my rows into arrays first, and storing them in a new table, so when I use "row_to_json" they come out as arrays?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select rows as arrays and use `json_agg(array_to_json(...))`:

```
select 
    json_build_object(
        'data', 
        json_agg(array_to_json(array[price::text, qty::text])))
from data;

                 json_build_object                  
----------------------------------------------------
 {"data" : [["11","11"], ["22","11"], ["33","11"]]}
(1 row)
```

You need a function introduced in Postgres 9.4, so SqlFiddle is useless.

Comment: `json_build_object` is from 9.4

Comment: SQLFiddle is annoying anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql) for that:

```
$ psql -U my_user -h my_host -c "SELECT * FROM my_table" --csv my_db | spyql -Oindent=4 "SELECT list_agg(_values) AS data FROM csv TO json"
{
    "data": [
        [
            "1",
            "David",
            "5.1"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "James",
            "2.1"
        ],
        [
            "3",
            "Joana",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "4",
            "Hellen",
            "9.8"
        ]
    ]
}
```

We are using psql to export a query/table to CSV and then spyql to convert the CSV to json. The `_values` variable in spyql contains a list with the value of each column before automatic type casting, therefore all values are strings. If you prefer having the casted values you can use the `cols` variable instead. `list_agg` aggregates all rows into a single array. Here's what you would get if used `cols` instead of `_values` (notice also the handling of NULL values):

```
$ psql -U my_user -h my_host -c "SELECT * FROM my_table" --csv my_db | spyql -Oindent=4 "SELECT list_agg(cols) AS data FROM csv TO json"
{
    "data": [
        [
            1,
            "David",
            5.1
        ],
        [
            2,
            "James",
            2.1
        ],
        [
            3,
            "Joana",
            null
        ],
        [
            4,
            "Hellen",
            9.8
        ]
    ]
}
```

For the record, I created the sample table with the following SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1, 'David', 5.1), (2, 'James', 2.1), (3, 'Joana', NULL), (4, 'Hellen', 9.8)) 
  AS t(id, name, score);
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of spyql